# Build Spring-Boot native executable on MacOS to run on Linux docker container

Tags: linux, spring-boot, macos, native, quarkus

I'm trying to build a native Spring Boot app from Josh Long's article: [Building Native Images with GraalVM and Spring Native on Apple's M1 Architecture](https://spring.io/blog/2022/03/23/building-native-images-with-graalvm-and-spring-native-on-apple-s-m1-architecture). It works fine, however when I try to build and run docker image and then below error appears:

```bash
$ docker run -i --rm -p 8080:8080 spring-boot-graalvm
exec ./application: exec format error
```

I've encountered same error with Quarkus, and I found out that it might be because I'm trying to run Mac executable on Linux image. For Quarkus it can be fixed by adding `quarkus.native.container-build` param to `mvn package` command.

Is there any equivalent for Spring Boot?

I'm expecting an option to build the image on MacOs which can run on Linux image container.

Comment: "*I found out that it might be because I'm trying to run Mac executable on Linux image.*" - This is definitively the issue. --- "*Is there any equivalent for Spring Boot?*" - Quarkus does nothing else than moving the build-process to a container. We can do the same with every build-process. For example, we can use [one of the images provided by the GraalVM team (`graalvm.org`)](https://www.graalvm.org/latest/docs/getting-started/container-images/) and build the whole application there.

Comment: I have the same issue. With Quarkus I used JIB and set the platform to ARMv8. I also noticed a AMD64 flag in the Docker GUI. 
Weirdly enough when building the spring project it does not have the AMD64 warning, and when I inspect the image it does contain the aarch64 architecture (which is what Apple M1 is using AFAIK). I haven't got a fix yet sadly.

Can you maybe also share your dockerfile?

Answer (score 0):

Found a fix:

Using this Dockerfile:

```
# Using Oracle GraalVM for JDK 17
FROM container-registry.oracle.com/graalvm/native-image:21-ol8 AS builder

# Set the working directory to /home/app
WORKDIR /build

# Copy the source code into the image for building
COPY . /build

# Build
RUN ./mvnw --no-transfer-progress native:compile -Pnative

# The deployment Image
FROM container-registry.oracle.com/os/oraclelinux:8-slim

EXPOSE 8080

# Copy the native executable into the containers
COPY --from=builder /build/target/benchmark-jibber app
ENTRYPOINT ["/app"]
```

(source: https://github.com/graalvm/graalvm-demos/blob/master/spring-native-image/Dockerfiles/Dockerfile)

Just make sure to tweak the app name to match your artifact.

More background info can be found here: https://github.com/graalvm/graalvm-demos/tree/master/spring-native-image#build-and-run-as-a-native-executable-1